# "Hi ladies" -- Is it rude to use this greeting for 3 people?

Tags: history, politeness, greetings

In addressing three people in an email isn't it more polite to use their names rather than "Hi ladies"?  Also when you walk into a quad cubicle isn't it more polite to address people by their names?   Grouping people together when there are only three is treating them as interchangeable, and is disrespectful isn't it?

Comment: What is a quad cubicle?

Comment: This doesn't apply to you as I suppose you're female, but "Hi ladies" is uncomfortably close to [the traditional catchphrase of casanova wannabes](http://www.google.com/search?q=hello+ladies&tbm=isch).

Comment: @Rahul: loved the link!

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the context, but in an informal context, even just "Hi" isn't disrespectful.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.  There are certainly women who would not like to be called "ladies".  It's old-fashioned and has been used in a way to limit women; currently, in the professional world, women do not want to be called anything but "women".  Nevertheless, I will say that among friends, it's OK because it's understood that it's almost a joke.  For example, my friends and I will have a "ladies' night" or a "girls' night" because we know that in the modern world we are "women" and so it's just for fun that we say that.  In this sense, it's just friendly, and I would think the same for someone who was my same rank and came into the cubicle greeting everyone thusly.

However, this does not seem to be your question.  As to whether it's disrespectful to greet everyone with one greeting or to greet each of the three cubicle mates individually, I would say greeting each person separately would be weird and seem like brown-nosing and wasting everyone's time.